# É possível ter um app com vários apps dentro?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Estamos pensando em desenvolver vários apps para resolver problemas, sendo que cada app resolve o problema de um setor. Para evitar que o usuário tivesse que baixar os apps separadamente, pensamos em fazer um *bundle* em que fosse possível reunir todos os apps em apenas um.
É se isso é possível de fazer com apps desenvolvidos com react-native? Mesmo que o *wrapper* fosse desenvolvido em linguagem nativa.

PS: Isso seria possível de atingir com um "projetão" em native, que englobaria todos os apps, mas por alguns motivos, como times diferentes alterando código que não é do seu app, preferimos fazer um app que englobe todos os outros.

Comment: Por que foi negativada? .__.

Comment: Você pode criar um app que exiba as páginas de acordo com as permissões.

Comment: @Marconi o problema não é a questão de quem vai acessar o app, mas sim de não ter um projetão com todos os apps ou um app separado para cada setor...

Comment: Não vejo problemas algum com varios aplicativos, pelo que vc está falando eu faria varios mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De maneira abrangente, sim, é possível.

#### PWA

Se um web app é suficiente suprir para as necessidades do projeto, sugiro fortemente utilizá-lo como alternativa. Algumas limitações ocorrem especialmente no iOS, onde a empresa da maçã parece não estar muito interessada nos aplicativos web. Porém, no Android/Chrome, a experiência é boa e o PWA tende a funcionar muito bem.

#### React Native com Expo

O Expo SDK oferece as atualizações OTA (Over the Air), o que permite que você atualize o seu aplicativo de maneira transparente para o usuário e independente da loja de aplicativos - na prática, o app baixa a atualização em segundo plano e na próxima abertura já está executando a versão nova. [Este artigo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates/) (em inglês) detalha o funcionamento e implementação.

#### React Native

Existem algumas bibliotecas que implementam atualizações OTA, como [react-native-bundle](https://github.com/mauritsd/react-native-dynamic-bundle) e [react-native-auto-updater](https://github.com/redbooth/react-native-auto-updater).

## Controle de Acesso

Partindo do pressuposto que será necessário controlar o que cada usuário pode acessar e você tem um mecanismo de autenticação, basta limitar a listagem dos atalhos de app (se estivermos falando de uma dashboard) de acordo com o nível de acesso do usuário. Entretanto, acredito que as ferramentas mencionadas não suportam o download condicional do código, logo, o usuário teria de baixar todos os "sub-apps", mesmo que não possa utilizá-los.

Comment: Era exatamente essas alternativas que estava procurando. Acredito que vamos acabar optando pelo react-native-bundle (:

Answer (score 0):

sim, você pode desenvolver vários aplicativos, quando diz "aplicativos dentro de outros aplicativos", entendo que esta fazendo alusão a uma central de aplicativos, no desenvolvimento web, criamos pacotes, estes pacotes possuem uma view vinculada, melhor dizendo uma pagina onde o usuário usará o "aplicativo", usar framework javascript esta na moda, mais será mais fácil você criar com php, o laravel por exemplo, com php você consegue criar um crud relativamente rápido, de pois de pronto, você migra para o react, sobre o aplicativo móvel, faça como o facebook, use a própria plataforma web, mais com dimensões menores.

crie algo com mobile.app.com e espelhe no aplicativo, você faz isso facilmente no android studio

a segunda alternativa, é criar aplicativos separados como o google faz, e usar um sistema de login sso, neste caso, teria um domínio central e os apps em um subdominio ou vir-se versa, algo como accounts.app.com.

Comment: Nesse caso, você está sugerindo usar PWA?

Comment: sim, o pwa é uma boa escolha, facilita para você também em relação ao seo e ao sxo, o google search esta cada vez mais exigente em relação a otimização da pagina para dispositivos moveis, você só terá um problema com pwa, o edge. a microsoft tem certa resistência a dar suporte ao pwa, que foi iniciado com a google, mais todos nos temos algum problema com esse navegador durante o desenvolvimento, nada que não possa ser contornado.

Comment: Nesse caso não teria muitos problemas, já que queremos o app apenas para celular...